# Create a pull request from specific commit until now

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit, pull-request

I have used git for a while to push and pull commits and branches, but I'm new to pull requests. 
I need to create a pull request from our development branch. This pull request needs to contain all commits from a certain point in time up until now. This pull request is for code reviewing purposes. I don't know how to go about this. 
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nevermind I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering how I did this.
I created a branch that holds all commits up to the certain point in time (commit id), using:

```
git branch review1 0b0shcommitid
```

Then I pushed this branch.
Then I was able to create a pull request from the development branch into the new review1 branch, that holds all commits from the given commit until now.

Comment: If you want that the content of the branch don't change, indeed, create a new branch is the good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote even though I answered my own question!

Comment: The upvote is also for the other ones that one day could view this question and will know that the answer is good ;)